# Read only error in assigning driver function to netdev_ops function pointer

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

```
void xbee_init(struct net_device *dev)

{
    struct xbee_priv *priv;

    dev->netdev_ops->ndo_set_mac_address = xbee_mac_addr;
    dev->netdev_ops->ndo_validate_addr = xbee_validate_addr;
    
    dev->mtu        = XBEE_DATA_MTU;
    dev->addr_len       = 8;
    dev->tx_queue_len   = 1000;

    memset(dev->broadcast, 0xFF, 8);

    dev->netdev_ops->ndo_open = xbee_open;
    
    dev->netdev_ops->ndo_stop = xbee_release;
    dev->hard_start_xmit = xbee_tx;
    dev->netdev_ops->ndo_do_ioctl = xbee_ioctl;
    dev->get_stats = xbee_stats;
```

**Even when I make my own structure like this :**

```
static const struct net_device_ops xbee_ops = {
    .ndo_open       = xbee_open,
    .ndo_stop       = xbee_close,
    .ndo_start_xmit     = xbee_xmit,
    .ndo_do_ioctl       = xbee_ioctl,
    .ndo_set_mac_address    = xbee_mac_addr,
} ;

dev->netdev_ops = &xbee_ops;
```

**It shows me this error :**

**assignment of member ‘ndo_set_mac_address’ in read-only object**

```
 dev->netdev_ops->ndo_set_mac_address = xbee_mac_addr;
```

Comment: `const` basically means "read only". That should be a good hint.

Comment: The last paragraph means you have to replace direct assignments to `net_device_ops` members and use only one assignment of the entire structure. Below answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your own struct does not help because it is not part of the problem.

If you look at the definition of [struct net_device](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L1282) you can see this:

```
const struct net_device_ops *netdev_ops;
```

This means, the memory where `dev->netdev_ops` is pointing to, is `const`.
Therefore you cannot modify `dev->netdev_ops->ndo_set_mac_address` or any other member.

You need to prepare your variable `xbee_ops` completely before you assign it to `dev->netdev_ops`.